# Assign ROLE dynamically to a controller action using grails ACL

Tags: grails

I can grant permission for different roles in controller action as below:

```
class ThingController {
    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SALES', 'ROLE_OTHERS'])
    create() {
      // creation logic
    }
}
```

that means, user with above roles can access the 'create' action. well, that's fine. But here roles are defined as hard coded. But, if want to add more roles or remove one of the roles from the 'create' action dynamically, how can i do that?

I tried like

```
String roles='ROLE_ADMIN'
@Secured(["'"+roles.toString()+"'"])
```

But gets error:
Attribute 'value' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but found type 'java.lang.Object' in @grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
 @ line -1, column -1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation is evaluated by the compiler and cannot contain any code. Its arguments must be constant expressions.

Instead of using annotations, you can use the spring security facilities in your actions:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted("ROLE1,ROLE2,ROLE3")) {
     // perform action
} else {
     response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN)
}
```

Comment: i tried but showing error: Cannot invoke method ifAllGranted() on null object

Comment: Then you forgot the import. SpringSecurityUtils is a class.

Comment: no i included the import statement on the above:                   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils. should i add any plugin for that. i already added spring-security-core-1.2.7.3 and spring-security-acl-1.1.1 plugin to my application.

Comment: The class is in spring-security-core.

Comment: showing same error. i added all the dependencies. also the SpringSecurityUtils.java class is existing in the specified path.

Comment: I use that code, it works for me. The error means that the class is not imported.

Comment: should i declare or inject class into my controller class?

Comment: No, that's just a static method of a regular Java class.

Comment: i removed injection and tested in my create action with this:    def create() {     if(SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted("ROLE_OTHERS,ROLE2,ROLE3")) {
           [assessor_advertisementInstance: new Assessor_advertisement(params)]
       } else {
           response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN)
       }

    } with no success. This time the above error does not show but always enters into the else{}statement. although i have ROLE_OTHERS role in my role_user table.

Comment: This method works as advertised. If you enter the else branch, your user does not have all of those those roles granted. If any of those roles are enough, use `ifAnyGranted`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. it worked now. ifAnyGranted has done the trict. I should have understood with the function name 'ifAllGranted' since the user don't have all the roles. thanks a lot.